# How is my Codable struct supposed to look like if the JSON response returns a dictionary if there is only one property

Tags: json, swift, codable

I couldn't find anything about this due to the amount of people that confuse array for a dictionary, but for my case its about the JSON response being a dictionary when there is only one property otherwise it will be an array. So how would i go about this?

```
    ....

    struct MessageContainer: Codable {
        var message: MessageDetail    // This will be an array if there is more than one result.
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case message = "Message"
        }
    }

    ....
```

Examples of Dictionary and Array response

https://pastebin.com/y0wgcJn3

https://pastebin.com/1kP1BB5f

Comment: Howdy, it's totally unclear.  Can you edit in to the question two SHORT (3 lines max) examples of the two situations?

Comment: Does this help you ?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905460/294884  it's really that simple if you have an optional "thing" in the JSON

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decodable for JSON with two structs under the same tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207841/decodable-for-json-with-two-structs-under-the-same-tag)

Comment: Those aren't the same problems, i am sorry if it was unclear. I had a problem of "MessageDetail" being either dictionary or array based on how many results it returns. The answer below did it for me, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a custom `init` method that converts a "single" `MessageDetail` into a one-element array:

```
struct MessageContainer: Codable {
    let message: [MessageDetail]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        if let message = try? container.decode(MessageDetail.self, forKey: .message) {
            self.message = [message]
        } else {
            self.message = try container.decode([MessageDetail].self, forKey: .message)
        }
    }
}
```